# Dictionary which doesn't create key if there are no values

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have two types `User` and `Area`.

```
    public class User : IEntity
        {
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public int AreaId { get; set; }
            public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
            public string LastModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
            public DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }


        }

        public class Area : IEntity
            {
                public virtual int Id { get; set; }
                public virtual string Name { get; set; }
                public virtual int DefaultAdminId { get; set; }
                public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
                public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
                public string LastModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
                public DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

                //Navigation properties
                public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
        }
```

`Area` can contain a whole bunch of `Users`. I was wanting to create a Dictionary where the `Area` name is the key and each key will contain the `Users` in this `Area` for the values of the key.

So this was achieved in an answer to another one of my questions using:

```
var dictionary = Areas.ToDictionary(s => s.Name, s => s.Users.Where(c => c.AreaId == s.Id));
```

This is great but if the `Area` doesn't contain any `Users` it is still put into the dictionary which is not what I want.

Could someone please give me some idea on how I would leave out the keys `Areas` which don't contain any `Users`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter `Areas` before sending it to the dictionary.

```
var dictionary = Areas.Where(s => s.Users.Any()).ToDictionary...
```

Comment: Great nice and clean solution you have there Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange for areas to have users wich do not match the AreaId that contains them but nevertheless:

```
   var usersByArea = (from area in areas
                      let areaUsers = area.Users.Where(u => u.AreaId == area.Id).ToList()
                      where areaUsers.Count > 0
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = area.Name,
                          Users = areaUsers
                      }).ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Users);
```